# How to not use -wrap for all linked libraries?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

My program uses several precompiled static libraries. I wrap malloc and free, but I want one of linked libraries to use 'real' malloc and free.
As I run:

`gcc [...] -W1, --wrap=malloc -W1, --wrap=free [used libraries]`

all libraries would use wrapped functions.

Is partial linking a way here? What if I link this one library dynamically?

Thanks in advance,
Jacek

Comment: Can't you just call `__real_malloc()` in that one library?

Comment: Not really, as I wrote it's precompiled. I mean by that, that it is 3rd party. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with some elf trickery on your binary static libraries.

Let's assume, that your library is called `libbar.a`. Then you can change all calls to `malloc()` to `__real_malloc()` with the help of `objcopy`:

```
objcopy libbar.a --redefine-sym malloc=__real_malloc --redefine-sym free=__real_free libbar2.a
```

Now, if you link the copied (modified) `libbar2.a` instead of `libbar.a` the original (not wrapped) `malloc()` and `free()` should be called.

Comment: That's brilliant! Although I was hoping for some more "clean" way, so nobody got a stroke while they read my makefiles